# NestJS, Mongoose - timestamps returning milliseconds instead of seconds

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs

Above the schema I have the following decorator

```
@Schema({
  discriminatorKey: 'kind',
  timestamps: {
    currentTime: () => Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
    createdAt: 'CreatedAt',
    updatedAt: 'UpdatedAt',
  },
})
```

And in the schema, I have

```
@Prop()
CreatedAt: number;

@Prop()
UpdatedAt: number;
```

Whenever I update some field, the `UpdatedAt` value is in millisecond instead of second as defined in `timestamps.currentTime`, `1638265771286` instead of `1638265771`. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I'm using `bulkWrite` which doesn't trigger pre-hook for `timestamps` and completely ignores the function provided in `currentTime`.
It uses an ISO Date object then casts the object to number which returns timestamp in ms instead of second.
Manually setting `UpdatedAt` to second in the update keys seems not to work.